# Keep text in SVG visible after zooming in

Tags: javascript, text, svg, zooming

I have the following text element defined in my SVG:

```
var data = document.createTextNode("Testing text in SVG");  
var text = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "text");
text.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size",'60');
text.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 2000);
text.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 100);
text.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
text.setAttributeNS(null, "text-anchor", "middle");
text.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "textLabel");
text.appendChild(data);
Root.appendChild(text);
```

Unfortunately, once I zoom into the SVG, the text is not visible anymore, which makes sense since the x and y coordinates are hard coded. How can I fix this, as I want the text to always be visible in the top middle area of the SVG no matter how much I zoom in and out?

Thanks!

Comment: There absolutely no way to know what kind of `zoom` you are talking about. Also if you are asking about `zoom` your code should illustrate that.

Comment: Well, if you are on a touch-based device like the iPad, it would be the pinch-and-zoom. In a browser, the same effect you get on Google Maps when you zoom into the map by using the mouse wheel. But I'm sure you're familiar with all this, hence I'm a little confused about your comment.

Comment: Probably you had your own crafted zoom. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your text element to the `svg` namespace and not `xmlns`:

```
var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
```

The "harcoded" coordinates should not matter. If the element is added correctly, these should be coordinates relative to the svg canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference after replacing the two lines that create the text element.

Comment: That's about it. I'm not doing anything special. Beside the method I posted, in a separate function I'm just updating the text based on where the user touched the SVG. But the x and y never change.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/etbsn/  I see no problem with it. I can zoom in (even on my phone) with no problem.

Comment: I didn't explain my problem properly. I can zoom into the SVG, but because the text was initially displayed at the top part of the SVG, now after zooming, that text is not visible anymore. If I scroll up I can see the text just fine, but I wanted that text to always stay visible no matter how much zooming one does.